# How to make ellipsis work in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, ellipsis

When I don't have `display: flex` on the `.container` the text properly truncates when decreasing the size of the container.

[image]

But the green block and the text aren't next to each other anymore, because the container doesn't have the `display: flex`. When I add it to the container, the green block and text are aligned properly but the text isn't truncated anymore (ellipsis are missing).

[image]

How can I make sure, using flex, that the block and text are aligned but also the text is truncated with the ellipses in a dynamic width container?

[my example codepen](https://codepen.io/dtaalbers/pen/WBPqYE)

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 20px
}

.text {
  display: flex;
}

.truncate {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">B</div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="truncate">
      3. This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flex item with the ellipsis must be able shrink below the width of the content. See my answer here for complete details: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmYyJM)

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed red; /* demo */
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 25px;  /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
                   /* set flex-shrink to 0 to prevent item from shrinking below 25px */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0; /* allow item to shrink below content size */
}

.truncate {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 20pt;
  background-color: yellow; /* demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">B</div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="truncate">
      3. This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @TomAalbers all you need is `min-width: 0;` on text element